# SlickEdit won't install on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I can't run the SlickEdit installation on my Ubuntu machine. Following the vendor's instructions:

> Run the installation at the prompt:
>
> $ ./vsinst

Here are the details:

```
$ ll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user    645648 Aug 12 21:46 vsinst*
```

system

```
$ uname -a:

Linux xxx-linux-svn 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP 
Wed Dec 4 17:28:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Details:

```
$ file vsinst
vsinst: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped

$ ldd vsinst
not a dynamic executable
```

So, it's neither architectural incompatibility problem, nor permissions.

```
Tried 32-bit libs with:  
sudo apt-get install i386 && sudo ./vsinst
```

In vain, same result:   ./vsinst: cannot execute binary file

Sorry and thanks for everyone!
The problem is in the 64-bit package offered by SE downloads page. Their 32-bit package works just fine.

Comment: And why can you not install it?  Seems installed to me... or can you not execute it? Please elaborate by editing your question :) And do not be too sure about it not being architecture: what does `ldd vsinst` show?

Comment: How did you install this program? What steps did you follow?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal, change directory using the command `cd` to the directory where the vsinst file is located, and run:

```
sudo ./vsinst
```

If you are installing the 32-bit version of SlickEdit in a 64-bit operating system, run this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs && sudo ./vsinst
```

Answer (score 0):

Does installing ia32-libs help?

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

**Source**:

[Ubuntu x64 unable to install SlickEdit v13](http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=3620.0)

Pertinent quotes:

> It sounds like your Ubuntu 8.04 x64 install does not have the required
>   32 bit libraries to run the SlickEdit installer, because SlickEdit is
>   a 32 bit app.
>
> If you download the support packages for 32bit apps you should be able
>   to get SlickEdit installed and running.

and

> I installed the package ia32-libs to get SlickEdit 12 to run.